# Generate datatable values dynamically based on inputs from another column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have created a datatable which has selectInput widgets in one of the columns. Another column of the datatable should take inputs given in the first column, and use them to look up a number from my data source. The inputs are binding correctly in Shiny, by using preDrawCallback and drawCallback functions, but lookup values are not updating when the inputs change. Strangely, they do update when I do the lookup in a separate data table. A reproducible example is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- data.frame(c(1:7),c(21:27))

shinyApp(
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

        Rows <- c(1:7)
        temp <- data.frame(Rows)  
        temp[,"Item"] <- ""
        temp[,"Value"] <- ""
        temp$Rows <- NULL

        sapply(1:7, FUN = function(i) {
          temp$Item[i] <<- as.character(selectInput(paste("Item.1.1",i, sep = "."), "",
                                                       choices = setNames(c(1:7),c(1:7)),
                                                       selected = 1,
                                                       multiple = FALSE))
        })

         sapply(1:7, FUN = function(i) {
           temp$Value[i] <<- data[eval(parse(text = paste("input$Item.1.1",i, sep = "."))),2]
         })

        datatable(temp, escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE,
                  options = list(sort = FALSE, paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE, dom = 't',
                                 columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:1)),
                                 preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                                 drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')
                  ))
    }, server = FALSE)
  }),
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)
```

That gives the error "Error in temp$Value[i] <<- data[eval(parse(text = paste("input$Item.1.1",  : 
  replacement has length zero".

I have tried adding this to server:

```
test <- reactive({
              data.frame(c(ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.1),"",data[eval(parse(text = paste("input$Item.1.1",1, sep = "."))),2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.2),"",data[input$Item.1.1.2,2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.3),"",data[input$Item.1.1.3,2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.4),"",data[input$Item.1.1.4,2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.5),"",data[input$Item.1.1.5,2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.6),"",data[input$Item.1.1.6,2]),
                ifelse(is.null(input$Item.1.1.7),"",data[input$Item.1.1.7,2])))
            })
```

Then, when I comment out the appropriate sapply within my renderDataTable and instead assign temp[,"Value"] <- test(), I get 21 down the second column of my datatable, and it does not change when the selectInputs are changed.

As a test, I have tried including this in my serve, coupled with a corresponding dataTableOutput() in my ui:

```
             output$test1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
               test()
             })
```

test1 behaves as expected if and only if the second sapply is commented out inside of renderDataTable. If it is not commented out, both tables have a column of unresponsive 21s.

This has been driving me batty all day, so any thoughts would improve my life greatly!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the select input values too early:

```
 sapply(1:7, FUN = function(i) {
   temp$Value[i] <<- data[eval(parse(text = paste("input$Item.1.1",i, sep = "."))),2]
 })
```

By the time you use these values, the select inputs have not even been rendered on the page yet, so not surprisingly, you get `NULL`'s. You cannot assign `NULL` to `tmp$Value[i]`.

Then regarding the failure with:

```
temp[,"Value"] <- test()
```

I don't understand what this means: `test()` returns a data frame, and `temp[, "Value"]` is a vector. I think you should use `c()` instead of `data.frame()` in the reactive.

---

Something off-topic since I really cannot help it: it is almost always a bad idea to use `eval(parse(text = ...))`. You can just use `input[paste("Item.1.1", i, sep = ".")]` instead of constructing the R code and `eval()` it. Both `input$foo` and `input['foo']` give you the value of the input with id `foo`. The latter form is more suitable in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I didn't know about the input['foo'] syntax at all!

I ended up using a different solution that had had a selectizeInput above the datatable, and then pulling in that input to generate my datatable rows, but I'm sure your advice will come in handy for future problems.